# How can I solve bitwise seive using 64 bit instead of 32 bit? What is the difference between these two?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

```
#define SZ 100000010
long long int status[SZ/64+1];
bool check( long long int N, long long int pos)
{
    return (bool)(N & (1<<pos));
}
long long int Set( long long int N, long long int pos)
{
    return N=N | (1<<pos);
}
void bitwise_seive()
{
    long long int cnt=1;
    for( long long int i=3; i<=sqrt(SZ); i+=2)
    {
        if(check( status[i>>6], ((i>>1)&31))==0)
        {
            for( long long int j=i*i; j<=SZ; j+=(i*2))
            {
                status[j>>6]=Set( status[j>>6], (j>>1)&31);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In line 20:

```
Set( status[j>>6], (j>>1)&31)
```

what does that mean?

And if I do:

```
Set( status[j>>5], j&31)
```

instead of:

```
Set( status[j>>6], (j>>1)&31)
```

what difference does it make?

Comment: @EugeneSh. i edited my question

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I removed the header

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: @Jabberwocky seems like some kind of Erastothene sieve.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher yes, now I see it, but it's up to the OP to explain this in first place.

Comment: Fully agree. Sieve is not enough.

Comment: Do not combine signed types, such as `long long int`, with bitwise manipulation, especially shifts.  Use unsigned types instead.

Comment: If you want an integer type of a specific size, then tell the compiler so: include `stdint.h` and use the appropriate type declared within, such as `uint64_t`.  Although some of these may be unavailable on some implementations, your program was not going to work on those implementations anyway if it depends on data-type characteristics that the implementation does not, in fact, provide.  This way you get alerted to that by a compile-time error if you should ever run into it.

Comment: I'd suggest `std::bitset` and avoid all these operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your flag 64 integers, one for each bit in a 64bits long long int. First, it should probably `unsigned`, as you can have `1 << 63` (and as NathanOliver said `1LLU <<`).

31 is `0x1F`, so you are forcing the shift to be less than 31 so that there is no problem with this shift (in the 32bits version, still issue with the unsigned IMHO).

The two operations you give after are completely different operations. The shift `j>>1` is done to remove the even numbers, as we know that these are never prime numbers (see the `j+=2*i`).

So two things here:

- `(j>>1)&31` removes support for even numbers, as the increase is `2*i`
- `status[j>>6]` selects the proper element in the array for `j`. But the value that you chose here is wrong as there are 8 bytes in a long long int, not 6. Also due to the previous offset, I would assume that the value is perhaps 9 instead.

edit: Wrong statement about the `status[j>>6]`

Comment: Is above my code is doing bitwise-sieve using 64 bit?

Comment: no, because you are only checking the first 31bits on each loop, so you never set the other 33 bits in the array element